# weird red line effect in games with opengl or vulkan from unity

Tags: games, opengl

normally changes in light are just making difference in brightness but in this case there are red lines all around certain area and where light is different, another red lining around that area is there. i've updated my entire system as much as possible yet nothing helped. this is only problem to unity games, even emulated have this problem so long the game uses opengl or vulkan

Comment: What system are you running, and what versions do you have of your GPU driver and of Mesa? Run `apt list mesa*` if you don't know. Also; what GPU do you have?

Comment: i run ubuntu 20.04, gpu drivers are nvidias 450 and there seems to be none of those mesa drivers. gpu is also rtx 2060

Comment: yeah nvidia drivers don't need Mesa, they provide the OpenGL/Vulkan implementation themselves. You're probably as up-to-date as you can get on 20.04 then. Pass I'm afraid; sorry.